# If a batsman get bowled on free hit and ball goes to boundary, will 4 runs be added or not?

Tags: rules, cricket, scoring

If a batsman get bowled on free hit and ball goes to boundary, will four runs be added or not? Is there any rule about this?

Comment: The cricket tag is enough. [Creating tags](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation) for every little characteristic within a sport will result in hundreds of useless tags over time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No-ball delivery

When a bowler over-steps, resulting in *No ball*, and the batsman's wicket has been disturbed with the ball going to the boundary, then 5 runs are awarded to the batting side. Five runs is split as one for overstepping and four for the boundary. All these 5 runs go into the extras (No ball) column. However, if the ball touches the bat/glove before hitting the stumps and then goes to the boundary, 1 run is added in the extras column for the No ball and 4 runs are added to the batsman's score. Either way, the batting side get 5 runs.

More details, including the excerpt below, can be found [here](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball,50,AR.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_ball#Effects_of_a_no_ball).

> 13 - Runs resulting from a No ball - how scored
>   The one run penalty shall be scored as a No ball extra. Any runs completed by the batsmen or any boundary allowance shall be credited to the striker if the ball has been struck by the bat; otherwise they shall also be scored as No ball extras.

## Free hit delivery

The delivery that immediately follows the No ball for overstepping in limited overs cricket is a *free hit*. This means that the batsman cannot be dismissed in any way apart from a run out, handling the ball, hitting the ball twice or obstructing the field. So, if the ball hits the stumps and goes to the boundary, the batsman is not out. Instead the batting team get 4 runs as extras (byes) for the ball reaching the boundary. If the batsman has nicked the ball before it hit the stumps on its way to the boundary, then all 4 runs are added to the batsman's score.

Long story short, if a batsman gets bowled off a free hit and the ball goes to boundary, then **yes**, 4 runs will be added to the batting side.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, however I've scoured the rules and I can't find anything contradicting it. At best the rules are in my view vague on this as they don't explicitly state what you can and can't do once a batsmen has been 'bowled' off a no-ball (or free hit). Are there any recorded examples of this happening in a match?

Comment: To be clear, I mean examples of additional runs being scored after a batsmen is clean 'bowled' off a no-ball or free-hit ball.

Comment: @Bogdanovist The rules for the no-ball are very clear and I don't think it needs any further explanation. For free-hits, I am not sure if it has happened in international cricket, but found this link which states it happening in domestic circuit. `On five occasions he clean bowled batsmen, only to hear the dreaded cry of "no ball" from the umpire, and three times he hit the batsmen's castle with the free hit that followed each no-ball. Two of those raced to the boundary off the stumps to give Greerton easy runs`. [Read here](http://is.gd/bDmaH8)

Comment: @Bogdanovist Yes, there are quite a few instances of batsman getting bowled off a no-ball, and scoring runs. One of the more memorable ones (for me, anyway) was from the 2005 Ashes when Michael Vaughan was bowled off a no-ball and the ball raced to the boundary. The rule is quite simple. In case of a fair delivery, when a batsman is bowled the ball is dead immediately. In case of a no-ball, the ball remains in play even after hitting the stumps, so if the ball doesn't reach the boundary, the batsmen can run and score runs (and of course, the fielding side can effect a run out).